# The following program prints the value of the variable. Why?

Tags: ruby

```
hello_world = 'Hello Ruby World' 

def hello_world
  'Hello World' 
end

puts hello_world
```

Please explain why prints variable's value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case of ambiguity when compiler finds a variable and method with same name in same scope, it gives precedence to the variable.

To call the method explicitly, send empty parens `()`

```
hello_world = 'Hello Ruby World' 

def hello_world
  'Hello World' 
end

puts hello_world()
```

or provider an explicit receiver to the method, in this case, using `self`

```
self.hello_world
```

**Edit**:
As `sepp2k` advised in comments below, `self.hello_world` would not work with a ruby(`.rb`) file. Just to try, you can dynamically dispatch the method with `send`:

```
send(:hello_world) #or
method(:hello_world).call
```

Comment: `self.hello_world` won't work in a Ruby file (even though it does work in IRB) because `hello_world` will be a private method (methods defined outside of a class are private by default - unless you're in IRB) and you can't call private methods with an explicit receiver (even if it's `self`).